# Is there a way to ask user, how many times the ball has to bounce and animate it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

recently im doing experiment on CSS3 Animations. I successfully made ball bouncing using keyframes. But is there a way to get user input and based on the input, ball bounces that much time?

Say for example, we need to ask user, how much time the ball has to animate.. User said "5" and now the ball has to animate 5 times?

here is snippit

```css
body {
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #ball {
            z-index:3;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin-left: -50px;
            background-color: #e65454;
            border-radius: 55px;
            -webkit-animation: bounce 2s 1 forwards;
            animation: bounce 2s 1 forwards;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
                    animation-duration: 6s;
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
            0% {
                top: 0;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            20% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            30% {
                top: 50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            50% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            60% {
                top: 100px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            80% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            90% {
                top: 150px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            100% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
        }

        @keyframes bounce {
            0% {
                top: 0;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            20% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            30% {
                top: 50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            50% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            60% {
                top: 100px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            80% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            90% {
                top: 150px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            100% {
                top: 190px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
        }

        #shadow {
            position: absolute;
            height: 5px;
            width: 100px;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
            bottom: 1.5%;
            left: 0;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
            -webkit-animation: shadow 2s 1 forwards;
            animation: shadow 2s 1 forwards;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
                    animation-duration: 6s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes shadow {
            0% {
                width: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px/5px;
                margin-left: -5px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            20% {
                width: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            30% {
                width: 30px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 30px/5px;
                margin-left: -15px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            50% {
                width: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            60% {
                width: 58px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 58px/5px;
                margin-left: -29px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            80% {
                width: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            90% {
                width: 80px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 80px/5px;
                margin-left: -40px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            100% {
                width: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
        }

        @keyframes shadow {
            0% {
                width: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px/5px;
                margin-left: -5px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            20% {
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            30% {
                width: 30px;
                border-radius: 30px/5px;
                margin-left: -15px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            50% {
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            60% {
                width: 58px;
                border-radius: 58px/5px;
                margin-left: -29px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            80% {
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
            90% {
                width: 80px;
                border-radius: 80px/5px;
                margin-left: -40px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }
            100% {
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 100px/5px;
                margin-left: -50px;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="ball"></div>
        <div id="shadow"></div>
    </div>
```

I saw few tutorials about, doing the same ball bounce using jquery function. so is there a way to accomplish this using jquery?

Comment: Take a look at the options to jQuery's `.animate()` method with the `easeOutBounce` animation.

Comment: you can add style using jquery with values provided by use. .css() function may help with this. just u have to take input from user and then add the css with these values